# How to fix 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined' in terser-webpack-plugin when building a new Vue CLI 3 project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I created a new project with the Vue CLI 3 (configured: babel, pwa, eslint, mocha). Running the test environment using `npm run serve` works just fine, but I can't build the project for production.

I installed the current version of the Vue CLI 3 and tried creating projects with different configurations. I get the following error message when building the project.

```
js/app.bb3f3c6e.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (/Users/.../untitled/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:176:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/.../untitled/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:13:40)
    at handle (/Users/.../untitled/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/.../untitled-adventure/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:188:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:828:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue [(`vuejs/vue-cli#3407`)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3407) with the `terser` 3.16 dependency.

The workaround is to install 3.14 for now:

```
npm i terser@3.14
```

Comment: I was configuring webpack and had the same error. and install `npm i terser@3.14` fixed it. thx